# Is it dangerous if a web resource POSTs to itself?

Tags: http

While reading some articles about writing web servers using [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/), I came across [this page](http://jcalderone.livejournal.com/49707.html) that includes the following statement:

> While it's convenient for this example, it's often not a good idea to
>   make a resource that POSTs to itself; this isn't about Twisted Web,
>   but the nature of HTTP in general; if you do this, make sure you
>   understand the possible negative consequences.

In the example discussed in the article, the resource is a web resource retrieved using a GET request.

My question is, what are the possible negative consequences that can arrive from having a resource POST to itself? I am only concerned about the aspects related to the HTTP protocol, so please ignore the fact that I mentioned about Twisted.

Comment: I have found that the [POST/REDIRECT/GET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) pattern addresses the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The POST verb is used for making a new resource in a collection. 
This means that POSTing to a resource has no direct meaning (POST endpoints should always be collections, not resources).

If you want to update your resource, you should PUT to it.

Sometimes, you do not know if you want to update or create the resource (maybe you've created it locally and want to create-or-update it). I think that in that case, the PUT verb is more appropriate because POST really means "I want to create something new".

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing inherently wrong about a page POSTing back to itself - in fact, many of the widely-used frameworks (ASP.NET, etc.) use that method to handle various events that happen on the client - some data is posted back to the same page where the server processes it and sends a new reponse.

Comment: I first thought at ASP.Net too, where you can check the property `Page.IsPostBack` to see if the request was submitted using POST. But I though that there might be other technical (non-compliant web servers, caching, etc) or semantical (how HTTP verbs map to CRUD-like operations) issues.

Comment: @npclaudiu I guess that could be an issue although if a site is served from such a web server I'd expect the site's author to be aware of it and then it's probably not an issue because of whatever workaround he/she may have used. As long as the site's code deal with the fact that a page may post back to itself I believe it's all right. In ASP.NET it could be a problem if a page receives a POST without a GET - the typical page cycle is GET first and then POST. Sites can work around this, though, so it's not a rule.